# How can I make a cron job that would only execute if my gpio pin is HIGH?

Tags: python, cron

I'm currently working on SiriProxy with my raspberry Pi, and I'm making a scheduled lighting system to siri so that I can give a command like this "Siri turn on my Bedroom light at 6pm". I dont know how to use cronjob as my scheduler.

Comment: google for documentation then.

Comment: what? I dont get what you are saying?

Comment: You say "I dont know how to use cronjob" so find out using google or a book.

Comment: yeah, but I need to use cronjob..

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one time job, you need `at` instead of `cron`. See [linux `at` man page.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at)